# Upsert support in ORMLite

Tags: servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

I am using ORMLite in my project.

What is the best way in ORMLite to perform UPSERT? Is there any built-in functions to do this type of operations?

Thanks
rudrvij

Answer (score 2):

There's currently no API that uses the native upsert feature in the underlying RDBMS but OrmLite's `db.Save()` API will insert a record if it doesn't exist or update it if it does.

You can request for OrmLite to natively support upserts by submitting a [feature request on ServiceStack's UserVoice](https://servicestack.uservoice.com/forums/176786-feature-requests).